# No member named 'minmax_element'in namespace std with xcode 4.6.3

Tags: c++, xcode, stl

The following codes can compile very well in VC 2010, but when I compile them with xcode 4.6.3 in mac, I have compilation errors as the question title indicates. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
         std::vector<int> x_array;
    std::vector<int> y_array;

    int min_x,min_y,max_x,max_y;
    auto temp = std::minmax_element(x_array.begin(),x_array.end());
    min_x = *(temp.first);
    max_x = *(temp.second);
```

Comment: Which C++ library are you using?

Comment: Have you included `<algorithm>`?

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, and I have included <algorithm>

Comment: what compiler are you using, and have you enabled c++11 mode in it?

Comment: @trojanfoe I use Apple llvm compiler 4.2 C++ Language Dialect Compiler Default

Comment: @trojanfoe I also try to use  Apple llvm compiler 4.2 C++ Language Dialect C++11, but still failed.

Comment: Neither of those options define the library implementation being used, which as you can see from my answer is where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-stdlib=libc++` instead of `-stdlib=libstdc++`:

```
$ cat test.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> x_array;
    std::vector<int> y_array;

    int min_x,min_y,max_x,max_y;
    auto temp = std::minmax_element(x_array.begin(),x_array.end());
    min_x = *(temp.first);
    max_x = *(temp.second);
    return 0;
}

$ clang++ -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++ -o test test.cpp
$ clang++ -std=c++0x -stdlib=libstdc++ -o test test.cpp
test.cpp:10:22: error: no member named 'minmax_element' in namespace 'std'
    auto temp = std::minmax_element(x_array.begin(),x_array.end());
                ~~~~~^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 0):

With cmake, the setting can be easily realised by the following code:

```
 set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x  -stdlib=libc++")
```